# network redirection of 2 physical serial ports

Tags: pyserial, netcat, socat

I have a question about the best way to redirect over a TCP-IP connection a serial stream and I have some restrictions:

1. The network connection might be unstable
2. Communication is one way only
3. Communication has to be as real-time as possible to avoid buffers to get bigger and bigger serial speed is different, RX side faster than TX side

I've played with socat but most of the examples are for pty virtual serial ports and I haven't managed to make them work with a pair of physical serial ports.

ser2net demon on lede/openwrt seems to be unstable

Had a look to pyserial but I can find only a server example to client example and my python coding skills are terrible.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a program to do what you want?

Comment: I hope to get it working with some bash scripting